# Serialize or unset non-serializeble object as part of serializable object (C#)

Tags: c#, serialization, serial-port, binaryformatter

Let's say I have an object of class ***MyClass*** with an object of ***SerialPort*** within it.
I am trying to serialize and save to file my object of "MyClass", but I can't , because objects of class SerialPort are not serializable. Skipping to the chase, I have something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }
    public SerialPort mySerialPort;

}
```

It appears C# does not allow me to unset or change type of mySerialPort. What would be the workaround in this situation?

```
mySerialPort = null; // obviously doesn't work
```

I need to access serial port from within the object of type MyClass, but I don't really need it when I serialize it. Is there a way to pass it as an argument during object construct so it's not a part of the object?

Comment: binaryformatter it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the field with `[NonSerialized]` to exclude it from serialization.

Comment: or [XMLIgnore] for a property;

Comment: Not sure who -1'd and why, but this worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: You may then consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.